# In RStudio, can I visually preview Spark Dataframes in the GUI like I can with normal R dataframes?

Tags: r, apache-spark, user-interface, rstudio, sparklyr

**Background**

This may be my lack of skill showing, but as I'm working on data manipulation in `R`, using RStudio, I'm fond of clicking into dataframes in the "Environments" section of the GUI (for me it's in the top-right of the screen) to see how my joins, mutates, etc. are changing the table(s) as I move through my workflow. It acts as a visual sanity check for me; when it comes to tables and dataframes I'm a very visual thinker, and I like to see my results as I code. As an example, I click on this:

[image]

And see something like this:

[image]

**The Problem**

Lately, because of a very large dataset (~200m rows), I've needed to do some of my `dplyr` work inside `sparklyr`, using a local instance of Apache Spark to work through some data manipulation. It's working mostly fine, but I lose my ability to have little previews of the data because spark dataframe objects look like lists in the Environment pane:

[image]

Besides clicking, is there a way I can "preview" my Spark dataframes inside RStudio as I work on them?

**What I've tried**

So your first thought might be "just use `head()`" -- and you'd be right! Except that running `head(d1, 5)` on a local Spark `df` with 200 million rows takes ... a long time.

Anything I may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I believe you need to call collect() on the Spark dataframe. So I would first sample the Spark dataframe, say .001% of the rows (if there's 200 million) with the `sparklyr::sdf_sample` function, and then collect that sample into a regular dataframe to look at.

```
samp <- analysis_test %>% sdf_sample(fraction = .00001) %>% collect()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Travis -- this could work just fine, I think. I'm away from the computer for the moment, but I'll run this as soon as I get back and mark my question answered if it works.